# Adding dependencies in a Maven sub-module when a profile is activated

Tags: xml, maven, dependencies, profile

I have a project with a parent `pom.xml` which define profiles, and a `debug` profile :

```
<profile>
    <id>debug-true</id>
    <activation>
        <property>
            <name>debug</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </activation>
</profile>
```

I want that one of my sub-modules adds the dependency `jboss-seam-debug` when the profile `debug` is activated.

I written this children pom.xml :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>debug-true</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-seam-debug</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

But it doesn't work, that dependency is not part of the dependency tree when I specify `-Ddebug=true` ... it's like the children pom.xml re-defines my `debug` profile ...

Do you know how could I add `jboss-seam-debug` dependency to my sub-module when the **property** `debug` has the value `true` ?

---

Actually, here is my full need which is a bit more complex.

Here is my parent `pom.xml` :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>env-dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>env</name>
                <value>dev</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <debug>true</debug>
    ... other properties ...
        </properties>
    </profile>
    ...
```

Generally, I just pass `-Denv=dev` on the `mvn` command line and wanted my sub-module to activate `jboss-seam-debug` only when property `debug` is defined to `true` so I wrote that in the sub-module `pom.xml` :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>debug-true</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>debug</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-seam-debug</artifactId>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    ...
```

which didn't work only by passing `-Denv=dev` because I don't pass the **system** property `-Ddebug=true`, it's the **maven** property which is activated by my parent `pom.xml`, and that my children doesn't "see" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's because profiles are not inhertited in maven. This means `debug-true` in child POM does not inhertif the activation of profile in parent POM also called `debug-true`.

You have two possibilities to solve this:

1) call `mvn -Pdebug-true` which will trigger the coresponding profile in each POM

2) add activation code in **each** POM

Personally I would prefere first solution.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be even a bit more complicated : [MNG-3228](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3228?focusedCommentId=231452&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#action_231452)

Comment: And I've just detailed my question which is a bit more complex and I can't choose a really "handsome" solution ...

Comment: I think the only solution is to name the profile also `env-dev` in child POM