# Maven - Downloading win dependencies on mac

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-shade-plugin

I'm currently working on a Openjfx project (for windows) using maven, so I have in my  POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>12.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

With the pandemics I had to travel and I'm stuck in another city with only my macbook.

I was asked to make some changes in the project. And now I want to generate the jar with the windows dependencies but maven downloads only the mac version.

```
javafx-controls-12.0.2-mac.jar
javafx-graphics-12.0.2-mac.jar
javafx-base-12.0.2-mac.jar
javafx-fxml-12.0.2-mac.jar
```

Is there a way to force the download of the win version of the files in mac?

PS: I'm also using Apache Maven Shade plugin for packing the Openjfx files in the jar.

Comment: It's downloading both `javafx-fxml-12.0.2-mac.jar` and `javafx-fxml-12.0.2.jar` in my Mac. Are you sure you don't have any `profiles` in configured in your `pom.xml` based on OS like it's mentioned in the 2nd answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650727/builds-for-different-platforms-the-maven-way

Comment: Yes, they're being downloaded as well, but what was lacking was the javafx-controls-12.0.2-win.jar and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found that you can specify what platforms to download the jars to make it cross platform as follows (according to https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular):

```
    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
            <classifier>win</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
            <classifier>linux</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```