# How to activate maven profile from command line (to build subsystem)

Tags: java, maven, multi-module, maven-profiles

I have a Maven project https://github.com/paulvi/MavenMultiModule1

with root pom.xml as

```xml
<modules>
    <module>MavenModule1</module>
    <module>MavenModule2</module>
</modules>
<properties>

</properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>p1</id>
        <modules>
            <module>MavenModule1</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>p2</id>
        <modules>
            <module>MavenModule2</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I would like to be able to build subsystem separately,
e.g. `mvn package -P p1`and `mvn package -P p2`

Both profiles are visible but can't be activated with `-P` switch

```
mvn help:all-profiles -P p1
```

That work with [other project](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/)

**What is missing here to activate profile or what is better way to build subsystem?**

I have read [How to activate a Maven profile in a dependent module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532297/how-to-activate-a-maven-profile-in-a-dependent-module)

Comment: I have tried both with and without space.

Comment: And what exactly is wrong with that? What do you expect and what you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your problem is that by declaring

```
<modules>
    <module>MavenModule1</module>
    <module>MavenModule2</module>
</modules>
```

Those are always built.
Just delete your first 4 lines and it will work as expected.

Now you can build MavenModule1 by typing:

```
-P p1
```

Both by typing:

```
-P p1,p2
```

and so forth.

Comment: Thinking about adding all modules into default profile, that is how it should be on CI.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need profiles to build specific module, use `-pl` flag instead.

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html

Answer (score -1):

You should remove that space and it should work fine.

use

> mvn package -Pp1