# In Maven 3.5.2, how do I use a profile defined in my settings.xml file in my pom.xml file?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Say I have the following profile defined in my ~/.m2/settings.xml file

```
 <profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>artifactory</id>
     </repositories> 
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>thirdparty</id>
          <name>scscm-thirdparty</name>
          <url>http://www.mycompany.com/artifactory/my-thirdparty-repo</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Now I want to download a home-built apr-1.6.2.tar.gz arfifact from the thirdparty repository id defined in the settings.xml, so in my pom.xml file I have

```
<artifactId>apr</artifactId>
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<version>1.6.2</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apr</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
    <type>tar.gz</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>apr</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>wget</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            # HOW DO I SPECIFY URL FROM PROFILE HERE????
           <unpack>false</unpack>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plujgins>
</build>
```

I see examples of profiles online, but they're all defined in the pom.xml itself, but that's not what I want to do. I just want to use a URL defined in my settings.xml profile inside my pom.xml file.

Comment: Define a property in your settings.xml and use that. But I don't think that's a good idea...furthermore I would ask why are you downloading a file separately ...

Comment: You're correct I don't want a property, but a profile. I'm downloading this file so I can compile, build, and package it into an RPM.

Comment: If you are using apr which itself should be available via RPM dependencies? Isn't it? Apart from that I'm not sure if it's really a good idea to use Maven in such cases...

Comment: apr is just an example. It can be ANY file.

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this in multiple ways

1. Set active profile in Settings.xml

   ```
   <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>artifactory</id>
      </repositories> 
         <repository>
           <snapshots>
             <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
           <id>thirdparty</id>
           <name>scscm-thirdparty</name>
           <url>http://www.mycompany.com/artifactory/my-thirdparty-repo</url>
         </repository>
       </repositories>
     </profile>
   </profiles>

   <activeProfiles>
     <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
   </activeProfiles>
   ```
2. Set active profile from CLI

   mvn clean verify -P artifactory
3. set active profile as default in Settings.xml

   ```
   <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>artifactory</id>
      </repositories> 
         <repository>
           <snapshots>
             <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
           <id>thirdparty</id>
           <name>scscm-thirdparty</name>
           <url>http://www.mycompany.com/artifactory/my-thirdparty-repo</url>
         </repository>
       </repositories>
       <activation>
         <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
       </activation>
     </profile>
   </profiles>
   ```

For more info on these options check [maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) page

Answer (score -2):

activate them via command-line (`-P <name>`) or with triggers what ever you like. but ask yourself, whether it is the right place to locate your profile. for further info look at  the documentation:

1.[Maven Doc](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

2. [same question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657318/how-to-activate-maven-profile-from-command-line-to-build-subsystem)
3. [Profile activation in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087457/activating-a-settings-xml-defined-maven-profile-from-pom-file)

Comment: None of the links provided answer the specific question I asked. Like, where did I ask about Eclipse?

Comment: hm I thought your question is about activating a profile in your build, thats the reason ...